# How to check that fortran real is compatible with C float?

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm bridging some legacy code between fortran and C using the iso-c-binding and modules/interfaces etc.

Normally, when passing a fortran array to C I'd just copy it into another array of the right iso-c-binding type. However some of the code requires me to pass a large (multi GB) array. In this case copying it is not sensible. Also, since it is coming from 3rd party code, changing the type of the fortran array no use `real(c_float)` is not possible either.

However I'd be happy to throw an exception, or fail to compile if the underlying fortran array was incompatible with the C float based API.

Is there a way to check whether a default `real` is compatible with a C `float` or `double` at compile time (or runtime)?

I'm using the intel fortran and C compilers if that matters.

Comment: Why do you say that copying a multi-GB array is *not* sensible?  What type of hardware is targeted?

Comment: @wallyk Primarily because I'm going to already be running close to the memory limit on the machine. Adding another 4GB in used memory is going to bring the application down- or push me into swap - either of which is unacceptable.

Comment: I suggest looking at the Fortran compiler manual.  However, in the days of yore (aka Fortran 77), REAL was also `REAL*4` as opposed to `REAL*8` for double precision — was that DOUBLE PRECISION? — so the chances are very high that Fortran REAL is the same as C float.  And if it turned out, by some mischance or contrivance, that Fortran REAL was C `double`, you'd be able to use the uncopied array, would you not?  AFAICR, if you modify the array in the C code, it gets changed in the calling function too — just like C.

Comment: You could try writing `real (OriginalArray, c_float)`.  If `OriginalArray` is of the same type as `c_float`, one would hope that the intrinsic `real` is written to just past the array.  If it is of a different type, then it would make a temporary copy of type `c_float`.  Maybe there would be enough memory...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in the days of yore the odds of working with a strange machine where these simple assumptions were not true were much larger than today (various 24 bit or 48 bit machines and others).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison between the kind of default REAL and the kind of REAL that is interoperable with a `float` in C is just a simple integer comparison.

You can make this comparison trigger a compile error or runtime error.

```
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_FLOAT    

! -99 is never a valid kind - so this will fail at compile time 
! if the test condition is false.
REAL(MERGE(KIND(1.0), -99, C_FLOAT == KIND(1.0)) :: dummy
```

or

```
IF (C_FLOAT /= KIND(1.0))  &
    ERROR STOP 'Default REAL isn''t interoperable with FLOAT!!'
```

C_FLOAT itself may have a negative value if the Fortran processor has no kind of REAL that interoperates with it.

(For some 15.0.x versions of ifort the following can be used for the compile time check variant:

```
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_FLOAT
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dummy_rk = MERGE(C_FLOAT, -99, KIND(1.0) == C_FLOAT)
! -99 is never a valid kind - so this will fail at compile time 
! if the test condition is false.
REAL(dummy_rk) :: dummy
```

Comment: For the compile time check I get `error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [MERGE]`

Comment: @MichaelAnderson The expression that provides the kind for the `dummy` variable is one that requires F2003 support.  I suspect you are not using a recent ifort release.  It works for me with 16.0.2.

Comment: Yep, stuck with 15 for now. So guess I'm stuck with the runtime version for now,

Comment: ok - with some versions of 15.0 if you simplify the expression for the compiler with some intermediate named constants it will work.  See edit.

Comment: I don't see that the KINDs of real*4, default real, C_FLOAT need be the same even when the floating point representation is the same.  I fail to understand exactly what is wanted here.  If you are paranoid, you might run old-fashioned tests to see whether the EPSILON values associated with the data types can be matched.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.

- C's `float` is passed as a `double` for C function parameters and expression evaluation.  This is easily overcome by passing a pointer to a structure or array containing variables defined as `float` (which really uses a 32-bit float).
- Intel's Fortran has several flavors of real:  `real*4`, `real*8`, and `real*16`.  By default (compiler settings may change these), `real` is real*4 and `double precision` is `real*8`.  See the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/579806).
- C's `long double` type has no equivalent in Intel Fortran, where—if  it were implemented, would be `real*10`—which it *does* use for intermediate values of expressions on an x86.
- Of course there is the major column versus minor column array layout problem (for more than one dimensional arrays) of C vs. Fortran.

If it were me, I would blaze the way for development by creating a test which passes known data (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, ...) from C to Fortran and vice versa and either print the values or compare them to what they should be.  If non-whole numbers are used, be sure to use an appropriate epsilon comparison:

```
           if (abs (c_val - fortran_val) > 0.00001)  error();
```